# Resource request Post XML

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I'm trying to send the xml that i serialized to string in this resource request but I'm having 400 error because of xmlString.. if I change it to another string, it works fine.. do you have any ideas? Thanks

```
var xmlString= new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc.documentElement);
    //  var xmlResult=encode_utf8(xmlString)
        Group = $resource(
                "http://localhost:8080/userapi/postgroup/:userId/:groupName/:xml",
                {},
                {save: {method:'POST',isArray:false, params: {userId:'@userId',groupName:'@groupName', xml:'@xml'}}}
        );

        Group.save({userId:$scope.userId,groupName:"name",xml:xmlString});`enter code here`
```

[image: EDIT ERROR PRINTSCREEN]

Comment: *"I'm having 400 error because of xmlString"* - what do you mean by this?

Comment: the variable named xmlString.. if I put it in the parameters it gives 400 error.. if i change it to "aaa" it works.. so the problem has to be on the xml I serialized

Comment: Have you tried logging xmlString to the console to see what it looks like?

Comment: yep.. check the edit image.. the first print is the xmlString and then the error .